# Responding to preference updates in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, preferences, preferenceactivity

I am calling a PreferenceActivity from another activity and then updating the application state (ie: changing the font size) on onActivityResult, based on the preference changes.

I was thinking it would be better to put the state update logic in the PreferenceActivity. That way I don't have the duplicate the logic in each activity that calls the PreferenceActivity.

What's the best or correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have any `Activity` (or other component) that cares about preference changes register a preference change listener via `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`. Then, when the preferences change by any means, they will find out about it and can react accordingly.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that even existed. Thanks a lot, CommonsWare!

Comment: @CommonsWare +1 for the general direction but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020446/android-registeronsharedpreferencechangelistener-causes-crash-in-a-custom-view/7021068#7021068) is much clearer and easier to implement.

Comment: Great method +1 . Also, _must_ call `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` when closing/destroying the component.

Answer (score 0):

The PreferenceActivity should handle all the preference setting. Your other activities should read what those settings are when they run and adjust themselves accordingly.