# Android registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() causes crash in a Custom View

Tags: android, crash, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-custom-view

Whenever I try to add this line it crashes my app. Am I not putting it in the right spot?

```
    preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(myActivity.this);
```

Here is my class

```
class Simulation extends View {

    // I declare my program variables here
    public Simulation(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // get the preferences
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        preferences
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(myActivity.this);
        String storedPreference = preferences.getString("nPref", "0");
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Log.i(TAG, "preferences changed!");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do like this

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefListener = 
        new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
            String key) {
        if (key.equals("date")) {
        }
    }
};
```

and

```
preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);
```

Comment: Excellent and elegant.  Didn't know this existed.  Works perfectly. +1 and thanks.

Answer (score 16):

One note about the Answer, the prefListener needs to be a class field, not a local variable or it may get garbage collected.

[SharedPreferences.onSharedPreferenceChangeListener not being called consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently)