# Use registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I've picked up someone else's code and been able to finally make it work! Right now, I'm working on the `PreferencesActivity` of my app. According to his code, the other guy was setting a `onSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in the `onResume()` and removing it in the `onPause()` like this:

```
 protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

It produces error `NullPointerException` and it's also deprecated. I will use it with my `PreferenceFragment` but I want to know why this code is there, what could be it's use and how to fix it and make it work.

Comment: I'm assuming the code snippet should say `getSharedPreferences()` instead of `getSharedPreferences`?

Comment: Yeah, fixed it, copy pasting messed things up o.O

Comment: Is there an `onSharedPreferencesChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)` method in the class?

Comment: Yes, you want to see it?

Comment: I found this question which seems like a duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7021068/1476989. Let me know if that helps you any.

Comment: Working fine! Still, I don't really understand its use, but yeah, working!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was caused by using a custom class (only a theory). Anonymously using the interface in the code (instead of implementing it in the main class) seems to fix the problem.

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefListener = 
        new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
            String key) {
        if (key.equals("date")) {
        }
    }
};
preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);
```

**Please note**: It is important that the pref listener variable is a class field and not a local variable, in case it gets garbage collected.

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7021068/1476989) for part of answer)